# Proof of geometric congruence using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We may assume some set $T$ of all triangles within the same plane. Let $R$ be defined on $T$ where $a\ R\ b$ if the triangles $a, b$ are *congruent*. We may assume  **congruence** to be defined as follows

> a triangle may be transformed into the other by some combination of reflections,  rotations, and translations.

It appears we must first define what **reflection** means. I am trying to find a very straightforward definition of what "reflection" means for triangles; it seems to imply  some kind of transformation $f$ on an element $a$ such that $(f \circ f)(a) =f(f(a)) = a$ and $f(a) \ne a$. But first, it seems there has to be a mathematically precise way to show the following hypothesis:

> any triangle $A$ can be represented two linearly independent vectors
>   $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $u, v$ represent two of its sides.

That is, I want to define "reflection" with some basic linear algebra definitions instead of assuming geometric facts like [SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28geometry%29#Congruence_of_triangles). It seems that I will have to somehow show that any triangle $A$ can be sufficiently represented by a linearly independent set $\left[u\ \ \ v \right ] $ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If so, then there exists some transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(f \circ f)(A) = f(f(A)) = A$ for $A \ne f(A)$, namely, $ (f \circ f)(A) = A \cdot \mathbf{I} = A  \cdot (A^{-1}A)= A \cdot (A A^{-1})$. Therefore, we have a precise way of explaining what *reflection* is, and that any reflection of a triangle $A$ may be transformed back into $A$ with a sequence of reflections.

This may not be the simplest approach to the problem of defining *reflection*, and in turn, to show precisely what this definition of *congruence* means. I still would like to persist with this basic linear algebra approach and ask, what is missing to show *reflection* here?

Comment: I don't see what is the question here... As a remark, your statement that "any triangle $A$ can be represented by two linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$" is true, but two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$ represent all the triangles obtained from the initial one by a translation. So to represent a triangle uniquely, you need to fix a point and two vectors, not only two vectors. This is not linear algebra, but affine geometry.

Answer (score 4):

A reflection about any plane $H$ can be realized from a reflection about the $e_1\times \dots \times e_k$-plane (in 2-D this would be $e_1$-axis)  after some rotation and/or translation.  Therefore simply define reflection about the plane by taking $-e_n$.  In 2-D this would be $f(x,y) = (x, -y)$.

You can actually define reflection about any plane, but done with the basis you're working in seems the most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Any congruence of the plane is a composition of at most $3$ reflections, which is related to the fact that the composition of $2$ reflections is a rotation or a translation.  You do not actually need to define rotations and translations separately under your definition of congruence.

Linear algebra is not enough to define congruence without additional nonlinear structure such as an orthogonality relation, a distance measure, or a dot product of vectors.  The linear structure alone gives you only affine transformations $v \to Av + b$. The closest thing to reflections that can be defined from vector space structure is (affine) *involutions*, linear transformations such that $T \circ T$ is the identity.  The involution is called nontrivial if $T$ is not the identity transformation.

An affine involution, geometrically, can be defined by taking any two intersecting lines as axes of a coordinate system and sending $(x,y)$ to $(x,-y)$.

A reflection is an involution that preserves any of the nonlinear additional structures that were listed previously.

Comment: The involution is assumed to be nontrivial in the last two paragraphs.